# WCF, Silverlight, IIS issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight, iis

Consider my scenario.
There is a WCF service inside class library project in visual studio 2010 and 2nd application is silverlight project. Silverlight project has WCF reference. When we run both in Visual stuio, they work fine, but when we host WCF on IIS 7.5. then its not working. Some error of cross domain access policy. But we have clientaccesspolicy.xaml and crossdomain.xml file already  at root level of both silverlight web project and the class library project having WCF services. We have same 2 files in inetpub/wwwroot directory as well.Any Idea how to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Sometimes you can get that error (misleadingly) when the client is pointed to the wrong address.  Test the WCF service address in the browser -- do you get an error?

Comment: What's in your clientaccesspolicy.xaml file? Does it allow access on the URL you use in IIS?

Comment: I bet the client still targets the development machine.

Comment: I got it to work in IIS on local though

Comment: already tested that and service is working in browser
(TEST WCF SERVICE ADDRESS)

Comment: How about your `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` element `<client> <endpoint>`? You need a diff endpoint for the server - you probably have `localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelled the extension of the file. It needs to be

clientaccesspolicy.xml

Not

clientaccesspolicy.xaml

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx

If it turns out that this is not the problem, put a HTTP trace on the server side and check that the client is successfully requesting the file. The Silverlight app should request this file before it attempts to make any WCF requests.